# PHP validar palavra-passe

Tags: php, validação, password

Não tenho grandes bases com PHP no entanto, preciso de fazer validações como:

- tamanho de string
- contem letras, maiusculas e minusculas
- contem numeros
- contem caracteres especiais

Neste caso para uma palavra passe, eu tentei fazer com regex, no entanto nao sei como que posso verificar se tem **algum** caracter especial.
Qual seria a melhor forma de verificar tudo isso.

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão abaixo engloba pelo menos uma letra minuscula, maiuscula, número e simbolo. com um tamanho de 8+ chars:

```
preg_match('/^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\P{N}*\p{N})(?=[\p{L}\p{N}]*[^\p{L}\p{N}])[\s\S]{8,}$/', $entrada, $saida);
```

Aproveite e leia essa resposta.
É bem legal e esclarece algumas coisas:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346033/7437072

*se alguém traduzisse eu "upvotaria" pq é muito detalhada*